# how to convert linq query into lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have written **Linq Query** that i wanted to make it **Lambda Expression**. how to write the **Lambda Expression** in place of return statement
**Linq Query**. entities tables are entities.Users,entities.Users,entities.ponds

**Query Expression :**

```
from pond in Ponds
join customerdevice in CustomerDevices on pond.Imei equals customerdevice.Imei
join user in Users on customerdevice.CustomerId equals user.CustomerId
where user.Username=="user1"
select new { temp = pond.Temp, imei = pond.Imei,timestamp=pond.Timestatmp }
```

**Lambda Expression :**

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllData(int deviceid)
        {
            using (smartpondEntities entities = new smartpondEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    return Ok(await entities.ponds.Where(u=>u.deviceid==deviceid).OrderByDescending(u => u.timestatmp).ToListAsync());
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Sorry Error Found!!!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have modified my question, can u plz check

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much a 1-1 mapping.

```
entities.Ponds
    .Join(entities.CustomerDevices, pond => pond.Imei, device => device.Imei, new {pond,device});
    .Join(entities.Users, devicePond => devicePond.deviceCustomerId, user => user.CustomerId, new {devicePond.pond, devicePond.device, user})
    .Where( e => e.user.Username == "user1")
    .Select( e => new { temp = e.pond.Temp, imei = e.pond.Imei,timestamp=e.pond.Timestatmp })
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, I'd suggest you add some navigational properties on your entities to shorten the Linq queries and have EF generate the joins for you.

```
public class Ponds {
    public string Imei {get;set}
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Imei))]
    public virtual CustomerDevice Device {get;set;}
}

public class CustomerDevices {
    [Key]
    public string Imei {get;set}
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public int DeviceId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId))]
    public virtual User Customer {get;set;}
}

public class Users { 
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
}
```

Shorting the query to:

```
this.entites.Ponds.Where ( 
   e => e.Device.Customer.Username == "user1" ||
        e.Device.DeviceId == 1
)
.Select( e => new { temp = e.Temp, imei = e.Imei,timestamp=e.Timestatmp })
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

You should then consider using something like SQLProfiler if you're using a MS DB to view, and then optimize the EF-SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You lamda should be :

```
var ponds = from pond in Ponds
join customerdevice in CustomerDevices on pond.Imei equals customerdevice.Imei
join user in Users on customerdevice.CustomerId equals user.CustomerId
where user.Username=="user1"
select new { temp = pond.Temp, imei = pond.Imei,timestamp=pond.Timestatmp }
```

Then query (I replaced deviceid with imei).

```
return Ok(await entities.ponds.Where(u=>u.imei==deviceid).OrderByDescending(u => u.timestatmp).ToListAsync());
```